# Send a workflow email when a choice within a list is chosen

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, email, choice-field, choices

I am looking for a vanilla way to send a link of a list to an email when a particular choice has been chosen within the list.

> Ex. When the choice "Ready For Review" is chosen, the workflow would send an email containing the link to the list to a chosen set of people.

**P.S:** All of the tutorials are regarding SharePoint designer or other applications. I would like to achieve this via SharePoint Online itself.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have access to MS flow?

Comment: Unfortunately, my organization does not allow access to MS flow

Comment: You will either need SharePoint Designer workflow/Microsoft flow to easily implement this. Are you on Modern UI SharePoint online or Classic one?

Comment: Hi I am on the Modern SharePoint online

Comment: You can only achieve this with MS FLOW or with Designer Workflow (depending on SP online or SP2013). Request this through IT if you do not have access.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by the workflow.

You can create the workflow and add the action “wait for field to equal value”.

Then set the choice filed equal to “Ready For Review” and publish the workflow.